# Scala: convert Option to Set

Tags: scala, set, option-type

How can I convert `Option` to `Set` easily, so that set contain one element if Option has element, and zero elements otherwise?

I did that manually this way, but it's cumbersome:

```
option match {
  case Some(x) => Set(x)
  case None => Set()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Option` has `toSet` method: [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#toSet[B%3E:A]:scala.collection.immutable.Set[B])

So, code from question can be transformed into just this:

```
option.toSet
```